# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fibo'

Tags: python-3.x

New to Python. Going through the tutorial python 3.10.4 and in the [chapter about modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), a simple excercise has stopped my progress.

I installed the module fibo by: pip install fibo. However when I try to 'import fibo' I get the following error:

```py
import fibo
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\<stdin\>", line 1, in \<module\>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fibo'
```

Any ideas?

I saw a few explanations in stackoverflow and some other sites, most address installation of the module, which I had already done. Some other explain, availability of the module in the directory where I am using the interepeter and I have already set the "environment variables path" to include it.

Quick note: If I change fibo to Fibo, I get an entirely different error:SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?. Just FYI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: That [Fibo](https://pypi.org/project/Fibo/) library you found is just someone doing the python 2 version of the same tutorial you're doing. And because it's python 2 it doesn't work in python 3. Just forget about it.

Second of all: You're **not** supposed to **install** anything at all! Notice how the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) states:

> For instance, use your favorite text editor to create a file called fibo.py in the current directory with the following contents:

And **that's** what you're importing in the next step.

Comment: Thanks, bro. I appreciate you taking the time.